# Poor pattern searching performance

Tags: java, performance, pattern-matching

I'm using a regex to search for a very specific pattern against a directory that's only about 106 MB in size.  It takes about 10 seconds to complete.

Is there anything that I can do to improve the performance?

```
package com.JFileReader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("/Users/me/Desktop/");

        if(dir.isFile()) { handleFile(dir); }
        if(dir.isDirectory()) { handleDir(dir); }
    }

    public static void handleFile(File aFile) {
        String regex = "[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+[@][a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
            Matcher m; 

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                m = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Found: " + aFile);
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void handleDir(File dir) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if(file.isFile()) { handleFile(file); }
            if(file.isDirectory()) { handleDir(file); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Searching a Pattern you should consider using KMP. Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use possessive quantifiers:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]++\\.[a-zA-Z]++@[a-zA-Z]++\\.[a-zA-Z]++";
```

When you use possessive quantifiers, the regex engine doesn't record backtrack positions and never go back to try other possibilities when the match fails.

Comment: Hmm... I guess maybe this is just the speed it runs at?  I made this change and didn't notice a difference.

Comment: @inquisitor: can you anchor the pattern (begining of a line, end of a line) ?

Comment: Yes, I can anchor it!

Comment: @inquisitor: begining or end or both ?

Comment: That made a significant difference!

Comment: @inquisitor: yes it will fail more quick.

Comment: I think you should first capture contents of all files at once  in a String and then use KMP to search for pattern.

Comment: @Algorithmist can you give me an example?

Comment: for KMP you can easily browse the NET, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/ has some tutorial about it and for accumulating the contents at one place it seems to be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling your regex pattern repeatedly (for each file) is a relatively expensive waste.

You could define that once and keep using the same instance.

Comment: I did this and didn't notice any difference in speed :-/